# Find $\delta$ for $\int_{a}^{b}|f(t)-g(t)|dt < \delta \implies \left|\int_{a}^{b} f(t)-g(t)dt \right| < \epsilon$?

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

I am trying to solve the following problem:

> [image]

Writing this using the definition of continuity, I reached to the following: I must prove that

$$d^*(I(f),I(g))<\epsilon \quad \text{whenever} \quad d(f,g)<\delta$$

Which translates to

$$\left|\int_{a}^{b} f(t)-g(t)dt \right| < \epsilon\tag{$\star$} \quad \text{whenever} \quad \int_{a}^{b}|f(t)-g(t)|dt < \delta$$

And this looks suspiciously similar to the following inequality:

$$\left|\int_{a}^{b} f(t)-g(t)dt \right| \leq \int_{a}^{b} |f(t)-g(t)|dt \tag{$\circ$}$$

I am a bit confused at what I should do now because the order of the integrals in $(\star)$ are inverted with respect to $(\circ)$ (supposing this inequality is somehow useful for the problem).

Comment: $I$ is even uniformly continuous.

Comment: @CSquared I am in the very beginning of a course in basic topology. I still can't use that.

Comment: either way, you have an error in $(\star)$ which is probably making it hard for you to prove this statement, and is also what Alex Ortiz was saying

Comment: @CSquared Yes, I corrected it.

Comment: okay, then continuity follows from the inequality in $(\circ)$

Comment: @CSquared With what $\delta$? I'm confused with that. I was expecting to get something like this: 

$$\left|\int_{a}^{b} f(t)-g(t)dt \right| \leq \int_{a}^{b} |f(t)-g(t)|dt \tag{$\circ$} <\epsilon$$

And then, I guess we could have $\epsilon = \delta$ but I can't use this.(I guess).

Comment: that is a correct choice of $\delta$. why do you think you can't use that choice of $\delta$? or is it that you can't use $(\circ)$?

Comment: @CSquared Ah, I think I understand now! We choose $\epsilon$ such that:

$$\left|\int_{a}^{b} f(t)-g(t)dt \right| \leq \int_{a}^{b} |f(t)-g(t)|dt \tag{$\circ$} <\epsilon$$

And we choose $\delta = \epsilon$. Now we have:

$$\int_{a}^{b}|f(t)-g(t)|dt < \epsilon\implies \left|\int_{a}^{b} f(t)-g(t)dt \right| < \epsilon$$

Which is true because of $(\circ)$.

Comment: you DO NOT choose $\epsilon$. you let $\epsilon>0$ and choose $\delta=\epsilon$. then assuming that $d^*(f,g)<\delta$, you show that $d(I(f),I(g))<\epsilon$

Comment: @CSquared Yeah, that's what I meant. It is that sometimes It gets easier for me to think of taking a decreasing sequence of $\epsilon$'s.

Answer (score 3):

It looks like you got the interpretation backwards. Given $\varepsilon > 0$, you need to find a $\delta>0$ so that $$|\int f-g\,dt| := d(I(f),I(g)) < \varepsilon\quad\text{whenever}\quad\int|f-g|\,dt:=d^*(f,g) < \delta.$$

In general, if you have a map $F\colon (X,d)\to (Y,\rho)$ of metric spaces, continuity of $F$ at a point $P\in X$ becomes the statement that for all $\varepsilon > 0$, there exists $\delta > 0$ so that $\rho(F(Q),F(P)) < \varepsilon$ whenever $d(Q,P)<\delta$. (In other words, "epsilon" goes with the codomain, and "delta" goes with the domain.)

Comment: Yes, I messed up when I was writing but the original title is correct.